# Min filter in Python using OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, filtering

I am trying to apply min filter to some images using the OpenCV library. How can I implement a min filter in Python using OpenCV?
Is there any function to do that?
If not, how can I write one?

Comment: Perhaps you want Numpy np.amin().

Answer (score 8):

By `min filter` I guess you mean running a kernel through each location in an image and replacing the kernel centre with the min value within the kernel's pixels.

To achieve this in Opencv you simply can use, `cv2.erode`. Documentation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaeb1e0c1033e3f6b891a25d0511362aeb).

But first, you need to define the size and shape of the kernel. You use `cv.getStructuringElement` doc [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gac342a1bb6eabf6f55c803b09268e36dc):

Example:

```
size = (3, 3)
shape = cv2.MORPH_RECT
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(shape, size)
min_image = cv2.erode(image, kernel)
```

Answer (score 2):

The morphological erosion is a minimum filter. In OpenCV this is implemented in the function [`erode`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaeb1e0c1033e3f6b891a25d0511362aeb).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answers, I implement in python + opencv the code that applies the minimum and maximum box filter.

```
import cv2

def minimumBoxFilter(n, path_to_image):
  img = cv2.imread(path_to_image)

  # Creates the shape of the kernel
  size = (n, n)
  shape = cv2.MORPH_RECT
  kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(shape, size)

  # Applies the minimum filter with kernel NxN
  imgResult = cv2.erode(img, kernel)

  # Shows the result
  cv2.namedWindow('Result with n ' + str(n), cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL) # Adjust the window length
  cv2.imshow('Result with n ' + str(n), imgResult)


def maximumBoxFilter(n, path_to_image):
  img = cv2.imread(path_to_image)

  # Creates the shape of the kernel
  size = (n,n)
  shape = cv2.MORPH_RECT
  kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(shape, size)

  # Applies the maximum filter with kernel NxN
  imgResult = cv2.dilate(img, kernel)

  # Shows the result
  cv2.namedWindow('Result with n ' + str(n), cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL) # Adjust the window length
  cv2.imshow('Result with n ' + str(n), imgResult)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  path_to_image = 'images/africa.tif'

  print("Test the function minimumBoxFilter()")
  minimumBoxFilter(3, path_to_image)
  minimumBoxFilter(5, path_to_image)
  minimumBoxFilter(7, path_to_image)
  minimumBoxFilter(11, path_to_image)
  cv2.waitKey(0)
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()

  print("Test the function maximumBoxFilter()")
  maximumBoxFilter(3, path_to_image)
  maximumBoxFilter(5, path_to_image)
  maximumBoxFilter(7, path_to_image)
  maximumBoxFilter(11, path_to_image)
  cv2.waitKey(0)
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

where path_to_image is a string. For example: 'images/africa.tif'

I obtain the following results:

**With the minimum filter:**

[image: result of minimum filter]

**With the maximum filter:**
[image: result of maximum filter]